# Unable to get space between the blocks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am writing a code to create 6 horizontal blocks with spaces b/w the blocks. but all the blocks are coinciding with each other and there is no spaces in between

index.html

```
<div class="a">
        <div className="b">
          <p>Principle</p>
          <p>Amount Spend</p>
          <p>Interest</p>
        </div>
        <div className="c">
          <p>Current Price</p>
          <p>percentage</p>
          <p>Simple Interest</p>
        </div>
        <div className="d">
          <p>Unitary rate</p>
          <p>percentage</p>
          <p>Invested Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div className="e">
          <p>Unitary rate</p>
          <p>percentage</p>
          <p>Invested Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div className="f">
          <p>Unitary rate</p>
          <p>Unitary rate</p>
          <p>Invested Amount</p>
        </div>
        <div className="g">
          <p>Market Vaue</p>
          <p>percent of profit value</p>
          <p>Unitary rate</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

index.css

```
.a
{
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.b
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;

}

.c
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;

}
.d
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;



}
.e
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;



}
.f
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.g
{
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;


}

p{
  padding-left: 18px;
  line-height: 20%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

[image]

You can see that in image screenshot, there is no space in blocks. I want each and every blocks should have equal spacing between them. I am just a beginer, so please suggest me how to modify this code.

Comment: just use `justify-content: space-between;` for the class a

Comment: hi, have you considered solving this with a grid instead of flexboxes? Would be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `<br>` or line breaks. Also, I don't use the diagram for padding and margining, I actually just toy around with a bit. I recommend for you to do that too, as that can help you understand the fundamentals of margining and padding on a much more intimate level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what kind of spaces you are trying to achieve.
To get spacing between the blocks use margin. I recommend you use the same class for every block to avoid redundancy.

index.html

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="block">
    <p>Principle</p>
    <p>Amount Spend</p>
    <p>Interest</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Current Price</p>
    <p>percentage</p>
    <p>Simple Interest</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Unitary rate</p>
    <p>percentage</p>
    <p>Invested Amount</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Unitary rate</p>
    <p>percentage</p>
    <p>Invested Amount</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Unitary rate</p>
    <p>Unitary rate</p>
    <p>Invested Amount</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Market Vaue</p>
    <p>percent of profit value</p>
    <p>Unitary rate</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.css

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.block {
  width: 15%;
  background-color:#D3D3D3;
  margin: 15px;
}

p {
  // If you want to center your text, use this
  text-align: center;
}
```

This should give you spacing on each element that has the `block` class.